# How to inlay plotly plot into a map

Tags: plotly, maps

I've created a polar chart in Plotly. I can post the code to create it if you wish, but here is an image of it.

[image]

What I need to do (and am unsure of the best way to accomplish it) is to insert it at a given lat, lon and be able to specify the radius of it (or at least control the size such that when the map is panned/zoomed it stays consistent). I investigated Plotly's maps but I don't see anything to even make an attempt at. Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish (although I need a much smaller diameter, this was just made in GIMP)

[image]

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: what are you using for your map?  **folium**?

Comment: I'm using Leaflet at this juncture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was multi-faceted to complete, but in case anyone has a similar issue, I've found a way to do this. Tools used are Leaflet for the map and Plotly for the plot.

**HTML For Plot**

```
<plotly-plot #myPlot style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;" 
   [data]="myGraph.data" [config]="myGraph.config"
   [layout]="myGraph.layout" [style]="myGraph.style">
</plotly-plot>
```

First, you have to make sure that the plot's layout is configured correctly.

```
layout : {
      autosize: true,
      polar: {
        radialaxis: {
          visible: false,
          range: [0, 1]          
        },
        bgcolor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
      },
      showlegend: false,
      paper_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'  
    }
```

Ensure that the background and plot to cover up the map.

Next, we have to export the plot to an image.

```
@ViewChild('myPlot') public myPlot: Plotly;
Plotly.toImage(this.myPlot, {
      format: 'png',
      height: 800,
      width: 800
    }).then((url) => {
      this.addPlotToMap(url);
    })
```

Finally, add that to the map via an image layer. This will be a circle with a two mile radius.

```
addPlotToMap(url){
    let TWO_MILE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 3218.69;
    let imageBounds = L.latLng(44.671613, -89.733720).toBounds(TWO_MILE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
    let overlay = L.imageOverlay(url,imageBounds);
    overlay.addTo(this.map);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have looked at two options on adding a **plotly** figure to a **folium** map

1. as **popup** where it remains as HTML.  This did not work well as popup would go into an infinite loop as well as no way to control background color of popup (so it covered map)
2. as an **image**.  This solution is presented.  This is effectively this: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/ImageOverlay.ipynb

```
import folium
import requests
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io
import io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# create a figure
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.pie(df, values="tip", names="day")
fig.update_layout(
    # showlegend=False,
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
)

# create a folium map with US state borders...
bounds = [-124.706553, 25.120779, -66.979601, 49.383625]
m = folium.Map()
m.fit_bounds([[bounds[1], bounds[0]], [bounds[3], bounds[2]]])
us = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/main/examples/data/us-states.json"
).json()
folium.GeoJson(us, name="geojson").add_to(m)


# add the plotly figure as an image to folium map
def plotly_fig2array(fig, lon=-100, lat=37, size=3):
    # convert Plotly fig to  an array
    fig_bytes = fig.to_image(format="png")
    buf = io.BytesIO(fig_bytes)
    img = Image.open(buf)
    return {"image":np.asarray(img), "bounds":[[lat-size, lon-size], [lat+size, lon+size]]}


folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
    **plotly_fig2array(fig, lon=-110)
).add_to(m)

m
```